# No json request was provided in the payload. (1269). Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios10, testflight

I am having this error constantly,

> I have been trying to solve for the second or even third time.

But it is very annoying, anyone know the reason for this?.

[image]

This started happening after updating to xcode 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a glitch on Apple's side that seems to happen pretty often.

Most people that reported it said that you just need to wait and try again:

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25377
- http://saintsatplay.com/blog/2016/05/xcode-error-with-no-json-request-provided-in-the-payload#.WA_fo5MrI6g
- https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/397#issuecomment-142131677